# Populating related table in SqlAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, sql, database, orm, sqlalchemy

So I have two table in a one-to-many relationship. When I make a new row of `Table1`, I want to populate `Table2` with the related rows. However, this population actually involves computing the `Table2` rows, using data in other related tables.

What's a good way to do that using the ORM layer? That is, assuming that that the `Table1` mappings are created through the ORM, where/how should I call the code to populate `Table2`?

I thought about using the `after_insert` hook, but i want to have a session to pass to the population method.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Thinking about it really hard. The mapping `__init__` method is out, as it's before the object is in the session/transaction. I've looked into sqlalchemy's various hooks. `after_insert` gives you a connection, not a session. My population code need a session. Is there an equivalent hook, but for the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking around in #sqlalchemy IRC, it was pointed out that this could be done using ORM-level relationships in an `before_flush` event listener.

It was explained that when you add a mapping through a relationship, the foreign key is automatically filled on flush, and the appropriate insert statement generated by the ORM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `before_flush` or `after_flush` [hook](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents.before_flush), it provides a `session`. You then check `session.new` objects for newly created models (tip: use `isinstance(object, ModelClass)`) and do your work here.

In fact, SQLAlchemy [recommends](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.after_insert) `before_flush` for general on flush changes.

> Mapper-level flush events only allow very limited operations, on attributes local to the row being operated upon only, as well as allowing any SQL to be emitted on the given Connection. Please read fully the notes at Mapper-level Events for guidelines on using these methods; generally, the SessionEvents.before_flush() method should be preferred for general on-flush changes.

Comment: I thought about something like that, but doing `isinstance` check on all created objects, let alone at all flush event, seemed extremely inefficient. I hoped this wouldn't be the only way. It seems to me that what I want to do should be a common pattern; is this really what is generally done?

Comment: This is as per recommended by SqlAlchemy. It may look 'inefficient' judging from this isolated case, but at a higher level, one is likely to require custom handlers for other models in the future. I implement a catch-all `before_flush` and re-route to specific handlers for individual model classes (v.s. multiple `before_flush` for each class). `isinstance` is unlikely your bottleneck here base on my experience.

Comment: Ok. What about other session events, like "pending_to_persistant"? This being an after flush event, does that mean that it can't be rolledback?

Comment: So `after_flush` is before the commit, so I guess I can rollback the original the insert if my population code fails.

Comment: In fact, "before_flush" doesn't work: the object doesn't yet have an id.

Comment: I recommend using `before_commit`, it's just a clearer mental model of a unit of work, and works as expected in a rollback. Do note that `before_commit` does not guarantee that a flush has been called, so it's not uncommon to do a `session.flush()` inside a `before_commit` hook.

Comment: Okay. Using "pending_to_persistent" cause a recursive loop if I add new objects to the session inside the hook. Not sure if there's a way around that, but I guess I'll use `after_commit`. Thanks!

Comment: (I meant `before_commit`, and unfortunately, `before_commit` doesn't guarantee access to the new instances, e.g. if there's been a flush before the commit).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings. I was not aware regarding `before_commit` not guarantee access to new instances post flush.